# Setting up JNA in Android Studio

Tags: android, jar, android-ndk, jna

I try to import jna.jar into my project since **JNA** is a very useful tool to call Native library which is base on JNI.

OS: Windows 10

IDE: Android Studio 1.5.1

JDK: 1.8.0_73

NDK: r10e

**What I have done**
(AS = Android Studio)

1. Create a new project by AS with API18.
2. Download jna.jar from their GitHub.

   > https://github.com/java-native-access/jna
3. copy jna.jar into project folder.

   > JNATest\app\libs\jna.jar
4. In AS, right-click on the icon of jna.jar, choose **Add as Library**
5. Wait for few seconds, check the File->Project Structure->app->Dependencies. We do have the jna.jar. (Same as app\build.gradle) 
   [build gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEmYC.jpg)
6. Implement JAVA code about JNA in MainActivity.java
7. Run app on real device Sony Z3 (arm)
8. Crash by `CLibrary.Instance.printf("Hello, JNA");`

**Error Message on Android Monitor**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                   Process: i3d.jnatest, PID: 1068
                   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native library (com/sun/jna/android-arm/libjnidispatch.so) not found in resource path (.)
                     at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:866)
                     at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:826)
                     at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:140)
..
... so on
```

**Java code**

```
package i3d.jnatest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        CLibrary.Instance.printf("Hello, JNA");
    }

    public interface  CLibrary extends Library
    {
        CLibrary Instance = (CLibrary) Native.loadLibrary("msvcrt", CLibrary.class);
        void printf(String format, Object... args);
    }
}
```

**Question**

According to error message, I miss `/android-arm/libjnidispatch.so` in runtime.

1. Did I put the wrong place for jna.jar?
2. How should I get and use `/android-arm/libjnidispatch.so`?

I am a newbie about Android Studio, so maybe misunderstanding something key-point.

Comment: which JNA.jar file did you use? I tried 4.1.0 and 4.2.2 but still got errors building for android

Comment: I am also facing same issue..have you got any solution?

Answer (score 13):

For Android, reference the JNA library adding @aar at the end of the string instead of downloading the JNA jar:

https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.md#jna-on-android

Answer (score 11):

Put the .so file in the following directory (when using android studio): `yourproject\app\src\main\jniLibs\armeabi-v7a\libjnidispatch.so`

**Update I: (up to version <= 4.3.0)** Since some of you asked where to find the *.so file:

On the [official JNA site](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) you will find all the supported architectures (30+) for download:

https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/tree/master/lib/native

Download the jar of the architecture you'd like and open it with some zip tool. In there you'll find the libjnidispatch.so file (of course only for unix architectures. For windows its a dll)

**Update II: (starting from version >= 4.4.0)**

**Use the jna-X.X.0.aar file, supplied by the JNA project**

As mentioned in a comment - starting from version [4.4.0 JNA publishes an AAR](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/4.4.0/) to maven central with all the libjnidispatch.so's in it.  Users have had better luck using gradle than straight maven here, which doesn't always select or properly handle aars.

Comment: not working for me! same error is coming! can you please help!!

Comment: Unfortunatly not because you did not supply any information on your problem. Please open another question here on SO and also others may help you...

Comment: Where can i find the .so file?

Comment: JNA publishes an AAR to maven central with all the libjnidispatch.so's in it.  There shouldn't be a need to manually copy.

Answer (score 2):

I found this comment in a file in the library github repo - "[If you're using Google's Eclipse plugin then you must manually remove libjnidispatch.so from jna.jar/lib/armeabi and add it into your project's libs/armeabi directory.](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/698625191a84eedfb9604b39feb0189e5e0d590d/www/AndroidDevelopmentEnvironment.md)"

Since this file was created in 2012 and Android Studio was still in very early phase and not super popular by that time, I assume it might be a valid note for Eclipse and also for Android Studio. I suggest you try it.

Comment: Thank you for this information. But I hit the wall when building the JNA source code.
 http://imgur.com/VQbH1F9
I will keep trying.

Comment: I build successfully by deleting some characters which are UTF-8 escape char.
Trying to do rest of steps..

Comment: You don't need to rebuild JNA; just extract the file from jna.jar and place it into your project's native libs directory.