# Best Architecture for C++ Libraries used in Android

Tags: android, c++, jna

I am compiling a c++ library to be used on my Android device.

In compiling the library I did not take into account the architecture I was building the library for.

As a result I have a 64 bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64 which only works on 64 bit systems.

I intend to link this library to my android device using the JNA tool.

What is the appropriate way to compile my c++ library for android architecture and JNA.

Comment: 32 bit I would say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the [Android NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/index.html).

Depending on the target architecture, you must select the appropriate toolchain/cross-compiler, e.g. ARM, MIPS or x86.

See also [Getting Started with the NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/index.html)

---

JNI or JNA have nothing to do with how the library is built. You must build the library for your target architecture, so it can be used on your phone or tablet.

To access this library from Java, you may use either [JNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) or [JNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access).

With JNI, you must implement glue code in C/C++. With JNA on the other side, you do more or less the same, but you use an existing library (libffi) and implement the glue code in Java. This is done dynamically at runtime and may be thought of something like reflection for a library.

Comment: I see. That would entail wrapping my cpp functions with JNI yes?

Comment: I was hoping to use JNA instead

Comment: JNA will work if your library exposes a standard C-compatible API.  If you are using C++, you need to wrap exposed functions with `extern "C"` and avoid using any C++-specific classes or data types.

Comment: Thank you @technomage That was a big help. Only issue is that the app works fine on the simulator but not a physical android device. I keep getting this error                                                                            java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native library (com/sun/jna/android-arm/libjnidispatch.so) not found in resource path (.)

Comment: Maybe these help https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/issues/268, http://stackoverflow.com/q/36305914/1741542

Comment: As noted by @OlafDietsche, you need to add JNA's native library (libjnidispatch.so) to your Android project just like your other native libraries.